# How to implement breadcrumbs in Angular as done in Windows File Explorer?

Tags: angular, windows, mobile, breadcrumbs

Basically, if the items in breadcrumbs are too many, I need the older ones to hide and only the recent ones to show  [How it's done in Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyjU2.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

just a note I have an input binding for dark mode and for checking if the page is welcome.  you can remove those because they are probably not relevant to you.

**interface**:

```
import { Params } from "@angular/router";

export interface BreadcrumbsInterface {
    label: string;
    params?: Params;
    url: string;
  }
```

*I use component declarations to feed if its the welcome page or not because I had an ngClass check.  you may or may not need this.*

**your.component.ts**:

public breadcrumbs: BreadcrumbsInterface[];

```
  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.breadcrumbs = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const ROUTE_DATA_BREADCRUMB: string = "breadcrumb";

    //subscribe to the NavigationEnd event
    this.router.events.pipe(filter((event: any) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)).subscribe((event: any) => {
      
      //set breadcrumbs
      let root: ActivatedRoute = this.activatedRoute.root;
      this.breadcrumbs = this.getBreadcrumbs(root);
    });
  }
  
  private getBreadcrumbs(route: ActivatedRoute, url: string="", breadcrumbs: BreadcrumbsInterface[]=[]): BreadcrumbsInterface[] {
    const ROUTE_DATA_BREADCRUMB: string = "breadcrumb";

    //get the child routes
    let children: ActivatedRoute[] = route.children;

    //return if there are no more children
    if (children.length === 0) {
      return breadcrumbs;
    }

    //iterate over each children
    for (let child of children) {
      //verify primary route
      if (child.outlet !== PRIMARY_OUTLET) {
        continue;
      }

      //verify the custom data property "breadcrumb" is specified on the route
      if (!child.snapshot.data.hasOwnProperty(ROUTE_DATA_BREADCRUMB)) {
        return this.getBreadcrumbs(child, url, breadcrumbs);
      }

      //get the route's URL segment
      let routeURL: string = child.snapshot.url.map(segment => segment.path).join("/");

      //append route URL to URL
      url += `/${routeURL}`;

      //add breadcrumb
      let breadcrumb: BreadcrumbsInterface = {
        label: child.snapshot.data[ROUTE_DATA_BREADCRUMB],
        params: child.snapshot.params,
        url: url
      };
      breadcrumbs.push(breadcrumb);
      
      //recursive
      return this.getBreadcrumbs(child, url, breadcrumbs);
    }
    
    //we should never get here, but just in case
    return breadcrumbs;
  }
```

**your.component.html**

```
<section class="py-.5 " data-animated-id="1" [ngClass]="isDark ? 'bg-breadcrumb-dark':'bg-breadcrumb'">
    <nav class="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between p-5 px-10">
   
        <ol class="list-reset py-.5 pl-2rounded flex bg-color-item text-sm
        inline-flex tracking-wide focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-100 focus:ring-indigo-500
        "[ngClass]="isDark ? 'text-gray-900 hover:text-gray-700':' text-gray-900 hover:text-gray-700' "
        >
          <li  class="px-2 text-base" *ngIf="isWelcome"><a [routerLink]="'../' + 'home'" class="no-underline" [ngClass]="isDark ? 'text-gray-900 hover:text-gray-700':'text-gray-650'">Welcome</a></li>
          <li  class="px-2 text-base" *ngIf="!isWelcome"><a [routerLink]="'../' + 'home'" class="no-underline" [ngClass]="isDark ? 'text-gray-900 hover:text-gray-700':'text-gray-650'">Home</a></li>

         <ng-container *ngFor="let breadcrumb of breadcrumbs">
            <li class="px-2 text-base">/</li>
            <li class="px-2  text-base" >
              <a  class="no-underline" [ngClass]="isDark ? 'text-gray-900 hover:text-gray-700':'text-gray-650'" [routerLink]="[breadcrumb.url, breadcrumb.params]">{{breadcrumb.label}}</a>
            </li>
         </ng-container>
        
        </ol>
      </nav>
    <!-- <div class="container">
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb py-0">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#"> Pages </a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">My Account</li>
        </ol>
    </nav> -->
    <!-- </div> -->
</section>
```

**your.component.css**

```
.bg-breadcrumb {
    background-color: #f7f7f7!important
}
.bg-color-item{
    color: #959595
}
.bg-breadcrumb-dark {
    background-color: rgb(229, 231, 235)!important
}
```